# The input field is not displaying it set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-input

i have this as next and back button

This is the next button:

```
$(document).on('click', '#next_form', function () {
        emailAdress = $("#email").val();
        $(".column_1").flip({
        direction: 'rl',
        });
        $(".column_2").flip({
        direction: 'lr',
        });
});
```

back button:
Then so i can revert the flip and insert the value again :

```
$(document).on('click', '#back_form', function () {
    $(".column_1").revertFlip();
    $(".column_2").revertFlip();
    $("#email").val(emailAdress);
    console.log(emailAdress);
});
```

but the input field is not displaying the value when i console log it seems to be running perfect but it does display... any ideas why?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/victorcabieles/5EsN8/ [link](http://jsfiddle.net/victorcabieles/5EsN8/)

Comment: In your fiddle the body tag is opened and then immediately closed. Is your actual code the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem was that when it flip javascript didn't register the motion so it didn't know the div elements had change, and had new content. so when i flip them back the same thing happen.

the solution that i found was to listen for mutations on the DOM.

```
   var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
        // fired when a mutation occurs
        console.log(mutations, observer);
        // ...
        $('#streetAddres').val(streetAddress);
        $("#numberPH").val(phoneNumber);
        $("#emailAd").val(emailAdress);
        $("#state").val(state);
        $("#name").val(Fname);
        $("#city").val(city);
        $("#zip").val(zip);

    });

    observer.observe(document, {
        subtree: true,
        attributes: true
        //...
    });
```

This example listens for DOM changes on document and its entire subtree, and it will fire on changes to element attributes as well as structural changes.

i found a pretty useful example and more information about it on stack overflow here is the source: [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener) you have to scroll down a little bit to see it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take `var Fname, emailAdress, phoneNumber;` out of the `document.ready`.

Comment: i tried taking it out but it creates an error when i do it  says the variable are not defined